# What does "null: false" really do?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I recently created a rails migration to add a Username to my devise Users.

```
    add_column :users, :username, :string
```

I created a test account and signed up without entering a username. The registration went through and created a user with no user name. I had to fix this since I need a username to set the profile url. So I updated my migration to:

```
    add_column :users, :username, :string, null: false
```

I thought this would prevent a user from creating a account with a null username - didn't work! I was still about to register with no username.

Eventually adding...

```
        validates_presence_of :username
```

...to my user.rb model fixed the issue. But why didn't null:false stop it? Why should I keep it and how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement:

```
add_column :users, :username, :string, null: false
```

translates exactly to SQL DDL (Data Definition Language) standard:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
```

The trailing `NOT NULL` is effect of `null: false`. You can use other [column modifiers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#column-modifiers) which some of them are directly translated into DDL.

Remember that if you already apply the migration to the database the further modifications should be done with a new migration file. Updates to migration Ruby files are not propagated to database schema when the migration was already applied. Eventually you can rollback last migrations and rerun them but then you may loose existing data during the schema rollback. See [Changing Existing Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-existing-migrations)

Comment: so shouldn't he have gotten a database constraint failure when inserting a row where username = null ?

Comment: You can't just update already applied migration file and expect DB to sync. You need to rollback the migraiton and apply again or create new one which modifies the constraint. Just check your database schema if `NOT NULL` is present at `username`. See here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-existing-migrations